# Making google maps responsive to resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resizing google map according to browser resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598955/resizing-google-map-according-to-browser-resizing)

So normally google maps using the js api would look like this...

[image]

Now if I was to refresh the page, with the developer tools up, and then put the developer tools down a bit it looks like this.

[image]

So I want to know how I can get it to redraw the controls and resize the map when the window is resized. I tried this code here. But no go...

```
#map_canvas {width:100%;height:100%;position: absolute; top: 42px; left: 0; right: 0;
 bottom:0; z-index: 1; overflow: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the style attributes on #map_canvas when the window.onresize event occurs:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    var style = document.getElementById('map_canvas').style;
    style.width = '100%';
    style.height = '100%';
    style.position = 'absolute';
    style.top = '42px';
    style.left = '0';
    style.right = '0';
    style.bottom = '0';
    style.z-index = '0';
    style.overflow = 'hidden';
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom());
}
```

A jQuery equiv taking into account the 42px at the top

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    var el = $("#map_canvas");
    el.css("position", "absolute");
    el.css("top", "42px");
    el.css("left", "0px");
    el.css("right", "0px");
    el.css("bottom", "0px");
    el.css("width", "100%");
    el.css("height", $("body").height() - 42);
    el.css("overflow", "hidden");
    google.maps.event.trigger(Maps.map, 'resize');
    Maps.map.setZoom(Maps.map.getZoom());
}
```

Comment: You will almost certainly need to trigger the google.maps.Map resize event on the map as well.

Comment: Also, it doesn't take into account the top bar. even with 42px there it doesn't fit the page. It gets moved down. But otherwise perfect

Comment: This doesnot work for my website