# make the width of my google-maps responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3, responsive-design

I have been searching for the right answer but I cannot find it.

I have a google maps API which I try to get responsive when I make my browser width larger.

In my javascript i have this code that interacts with my HTML DIV

```
  ui.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapParams);
    ui.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
map.setCenter(homeLatlng);
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="map_canvas" class="map"></div>
```

My CSS responsive code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
#map_canvas {
margin:0 auto; height:600px; min-width:450px; max-width:750px; float:right;
```

The problem is that my google MAP stays at 450px..
Does anybody knows why my google map doesnt become larger when i make my browser width size bigger?

Comment: There are numerous divs inside #map_canvas. Check to make sure those divs have a width of 100%.

Comment: Your answer lies at the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598955/resizing-google-map-according-to-browser-resizing

Comment: How are you embedding the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the `width` of `#map_canvas` in the css equal 100%. That way it'll stretch in relation to the width of the parent container. It'll still obey the `min-width` and `max-width` properties if those limits are reached when you resize your browser.